# Polymer bind object dom-repeate

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I run on loop on the list (this is array). and for every I create icon-status with property item.status.

I want that is item.status changed for some reason also the property to the icon will change.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{list}}">

        <paper-item>
            <paper-item-body>
                <div class="horizontal  layout font-md">
                    //this is also dont bind on change
                    <icon-status state={{item.status}} size=7></icon-status>


                    <div class="flex"></div>
                    //this is not bind on change
                    <div class="gray">{{item.status}}</div>
                </div>
            </paper-item-body>
        </paper-item>

    </div>

    </div>
</template>
```

I tried using timeout change the status of the items and the view does not update.
How can I bind this?

Thanks

Comment: 1. What are those two random divs at the end of the `template`? and 2. How are you updating the `list` object? Are you using `this.push`?

Comment: oops the divs is mistake.. 
I update the list object go to the list[0].status='newstauts';

I dont add new elements to the array. only change the inside.

Comment: Try `this.set('list.0.status', 'newStatus');`

Comment: See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#array-binding

Comment: this is works.but only from inside. I want to bind also from outside.from another element. the list change also from outside.

Comment: Then the array, `list`, has to be exposed as a property on the element with `notify: true`. Also, you should make the array one-way binded, `items="[[list]]"` because  the data is only flowing in one direction.

Answer (score 0):

To add binding support for `list`:

1. To update the value in the current element, use `this.set('list.0.status', 'newStatus');`
2. To update the value in a parent element, add `list` as a property on the current element:

   `list: { type: Array, notify: true }`
3. Consider changing your `template` binding from two-way to one-way as the data is only flowing in one direction, `<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[list]]">`